# Mysql: Find higher value for the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data set (snippet):

[image]

This is an extraction from a test management tools dumped into mysql. What you are seeing is a view that marges tests and run results.
You have tests (test_id, test names) associated to runs (

86 rows
66 unique test_ids

Problem:

let's take test_id 84013.
as you can see, we have 2 runs, run at different times. 
Of the 2, I want the latest.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_results A INNER JOIN test_results B ON A.test_Id = B.test_Id 
WHERE A.started > B.started
```

But this gives me only 21 total rows, where I expect at least 66 (unique test_id, run results).

What can I do ?

I'd like a pure SQL approach, but happy to use Python as well.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` test_id

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Thank you @Bibin Matthew that was a useful hint

Answer (score 2):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX` aggregation on the date column:

```
SELECT test_id, MAX(started)
FROM test_results
GROUP BY test_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the row with max date for each tests and then display the information of this row:

You can use a group by and determine wich is the last date of each test then select the row with the same id and the max date

```
SELECT *
FROM test_results tr
JOIN
  ( SELECT test_id ,
           max(started) maxdate
   FROM test_results
   GROUP BY test_id ) tmax ON tr.test_id = tmax.test_id
AND tr.started = tmax.maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which does not need to use GROUPBY, which suffers with poor performance while you have a large number of rows to obtain the result.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test_results t1 LEFT JOIN test_results t2
 ON (t1.test_Id = t2.test_Id and t1.started < t2.started)
WHERE t2.started IS NULL
```

The idea is that the last row in each group cannot find a match which has newer `started`.

You can see the original here http://fellowtuts.com/mysql/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/